# How to output WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control setting?

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm using the `WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control` for the user to upload and crop an image in the Customizer. However, the get theme mod function doesn't seem to be working for outputting it as I usually do.

This is what I have in my customizer.php file:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'bio_image', array(
    'default'           => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default.jpg',
    'transport'         => 'postMessage'
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'bio_image', array(
    'label'             => __( 'bio_image', 'myTheme' ),
    'flex_width'        => false, 
    'flex_height'       => false,
    'width'             => 200,
    'height'            => 200,
    'settings'          => 'bio_image',
) ) );
```

This is what I have in my template file:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'bio_image' , get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default.jpg' ); ?>">
```

This only displays the `default.jpg` image, and at the wrong dimensions.

Is there another way of outputting the cropped image?

Comment: Are you certain it saves a URL and not an ID? Are you certain the image is being saved?

Answer (score 2):

The theme mod here is storing the attachment post ID whereas your default value is a URL. So what you'd need to do is something like:

```
<?php
function get_bio_image_url() {
    if ( get_theme_mod( 'bio_image' ) > 0 ) {
        return wp_get_attachment_url( get_theme_mod( 'bio_image' ) );
    } else {
        return get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default.jpg';
    }
}
?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_bio_image_url() ); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me, simplifying [Weston's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/8521/weston-ruter) answer above.

```
<img id="bio-image" src="<?php 
    if ( get_theme_mod( 'bio_image' ) > 0 ) { 
        echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_theme_mod( 'bio_image' ) ); 
    } else { 
        echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default.jpg'); 
    } 
?>">
```

However, the problem now is in the Customizer. The default image that I have set in `WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control` doesn't show up, nor does newly uploaded images because it outputs the image ID instead of the URL. The code I have below in my customizer.js is looking for the URL:

```
wp.customize( 'bio_image', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        $('#bio-image').attr( 'src', newval );
    } );
} );
```

Does anyone know how to get the URL form the ID in jquery?